# Why won't gradle jar build a jar that gradle build does?

Tags: gradle

In my Gradle project, I define an additional sourceSet.

```
sourceSets {
    sample {
        java {
            srcDir 'sample/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }
}
```

I then add a task:

```
task sampleJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sample'
    from sourceSets.sample.output
}

artifacts {
    archives sampleJar
}
```

If I do `> gradle build` the additional jar file builds from the additional source set.  However, if I do `> gradle jar`, it doesn't.  any reason why?

When I go through the output messages, I see:

`gradle build` has `sampleJar` in the Tasks to be executed:

but

`gradle jar` doesn't.

But unsure as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `jar` is just the task that assembles the main jar file.

`build`, on the other hand, is the top-level life-cycle task, which depends on `assemble`. And `assemble` is [documented as](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks)

> Depends on: jar, and all other tasks that create artifacts attached to the archives configuration.

Since your `sampleJar` pecisely creates an artifact attached to the archives configuration, `assemble`, and thus `build` depends on it.